# MVC img src find and change in html string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

Hello I have html text in this html text there are two img(there may be more than 2 img) I want to take this img's src and change it. Change operation will be in server side so. 
In js I wrote

```
 $(content).find('img').each(function () {
                var src = $(this).attr('src');

                if (src !== "" || src != null)                  
                    //var result = content.replace(src, changeImageUrls(src));


            });
```

content is html string. With this code I find src of img but after this I will send it to controller.

```
function changeImageUrls(urls) {
            console.log(urls);
            var newurl = "";
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("Upload", "Media")',
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    url: urls
                }),
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.Status !== 200) {

                        toastr.warning('@Resources.Resource.Error_Unexpected');
                        return;
                    }
                    if (data.Result === "FILE_COULDNT_SAVED") {
                        toastr.warning('Sayfa tasarımı kaydedilemedi.');
                        return;
                    }
                    newurl = data.Result;
                    console.log("Yeni url verildi");
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    toastr.warning('@Resources.Resource.Error_Unexpected');
                    return;
                }
            });
            return newurl;

        }
```

I wrote this function two post data to controller.

```
  [HttpPost]

        public ActionResult Upload(string url)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
                return Content(Serialization.JsonSerialize(new { Status = 400 }));

            return Content(Serialization.JsonSerialize(new { Status = 200, Result = MediaRepository.Upload(url) }));
        }
```

When I post to controller , controller get url always null.I couldn't find the problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: change `data: JSON.stringify({
                    url: urls
                })` to `data: {
                    url: urls
                }]`

Comment: `async: false`? Seriously?

Comment: You can also just use `return Json(new { Status = 400 });` instead of building the `Content()` yourself